# Pre-assign parameter in script

Tags: c++, parameters, printf

Actually I have trouble naming the title of this post. Because I don't know how to summarize my meaning in a professional way. But I'll explain my question as below:

I'm running a program written by C++, command is:

```
./VariationHunter_SC
```

Then it'll let you type in many parameters:

```
Please enter the minimum paired-end insert size:

Please enter the maximum paired-end insert size:

Please enter the pre-processing mapping prune probability:

Please enter the name of the input file:

Please enter the minimum support for a cluster:
```

Obviously I need to type in such parameters one by one to run the program; But I have thousands of such jobs, and need to pre-assign such parameters in script, and submit script to computer.
So how can I do that?

thx

Edit
so how can I make parameter-list?
Just like below?:

```
140
160
0
mrfast.vh
1
```

Seems the program cannot recognize these numbers, and distribute numbers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how the program actually reads the data that you type in - it's likely that its reading `stdin`, so you could use separate files with the parameters and pass them in via  redirection: `./VariationHunter_SC < parameter-file`

It's also possible that the program will accept parameters on the command line, but there's no way of really knowing that (or how) except by whatever documentation the program might come with (or by reading the source code, if it's available and there is no other accurate docs).

Comment: thx....but how can I make this 'parameter-file'? just list the numbers??? Look at my edit..

Comment: In your question you have 5 prompts - you'd probably put into the file 5 lines that have exactly what you'd type in reponse to the those prompts. Use whatever is your preferred text editor to create the file (notepad, gedit, vi, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the piping character to pipe the contents of a file to your program
example, in a windows command shell:
echo "asdf" | pause
This will pass "asdf" to the pause program. As a result, pause will print a "Press any key to continue" message, then imediately continue because it will receive the "asdf" string as a response.

So, overall, write or use a program that outputs the contents of your file. Call it, then pipe its output to the program that needs the input.

The unix **cat** command is such a command that writes the contents of a file to output, or to the input of another executable if you are piping the output.